# Mule ESB as a message router for TCP based messaging protocols ( multiple persistent connections )

Tags: mule, mule-el

Mule ESB as a message router for TCP based messaging protocols ( multiple persistent connections )
Would Mule ESB be suitable for building up application with Server and Client endpoints which would offer persistent TCP connections on both Server and Client sides, where there should be direct mapping between the connection on Server and Client sides. It should also be able to support multiple tcp concurrent TCP connections on both sides. Is this about building a Transport and/or Connectors ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Mule can certainly do that. We built an in-house app that act as a server accepting incoming persistent TCP connections.

Comment: Hi Timpham, thanks for your comments. One more question, as you said you have a in-house app that acts as a server. Do you have also a client side for this APP, where Mule is used for the routing and message processing, while the outgoing messages are sent through the client side of the APP ? and if you do that, do you do some kind of connection mapping between the Server and the Client side ?

Comment: Yes. Your Mule app can connect to other backend systems either via TCP  or JMS or JDBC, etc...That's the goal of Mule, accepting incoming messages, process and/or route them to other systems.